# How do you specify which wireless drivers get loaded?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, firmware

I'm trying to resolve issues with my wifi running slowly relative to other computers on the same network/location. When connected to the local network a speedtest.net runs at 1-2Mbit from my computer, but when I USB tether to my phone and connect it to the same wifi network (cellular data off) I get 100Mbit+ speed tests.

I've been trying to play with the drivers from https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware, though I don't know what I'm doing very well.

It appears that I'm loading firmware from `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin`, I notice that there's a directory `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0`, I am wondering if I should experiment with loading other firmware versions available?

If I can try this, can someone tell me how I go about directing the OS to load a different firmware version?

Running linux mint 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the loaded driver you can use the `lsmod` command or through `less /proc/modules` command.

To get some information about the loaded kernel module you can use the following command:

```
modinfo the_kernel_module_here
```

it will display the path to the loaded kernel module `filename` , the `firmware` and the version : `version` .